# cross-platform automatic build of non-C projects

Tags: java, c++, build, cmake, pascal

Actually, I need to build binaries for different languages - Java, Pascal (Delphi/FPC), C++, C#, etc under Windows / Linux platforms.

How this could be done? I am using CMake for C projects for now like this:

`cmake --build .` with `CMakeLists.txt` providen.

Comment: Writing cross platform builds and applications is a complex subject. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: yes. how can i configure CMake to compile java/pascal/delphi/c# files? i can create a custom `CMakeLists.txt` file for each source i have.

Comment: A serious Java project should come with a build procedure based on Ant, Maven, Gradle or any other build tool already. I've never seen any Java project built with cmake. It's just not the right tool for the job. Also, a Java binary is inherently cross-platform. You can build it on Windows and run it on Linux.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, i know that. I just want to make build process common for all languages my software supports. For java, i think, i can use `javac` and `java` commands to compile and run, respectively. But i really have no idea on how to make it common to run `java %s` for a java binaries and `./%s` with standard (C++, Pascal) binaries...

Comment: You are better off using CMake to call maven (or ant) as these tools are designed for Java.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. Use the right tool for the job. Nobody builds Java projects with cmake.

Comment: i have chosen this way because my java application could not invoke `cl.exe` (MSVC compiler) correctly - it does not find any of `include paths` set in the PATH var. Although, PATH variable is set correctly and running the same command from `cmd.exe` just works... i have no correct ideas left...

Comment: @shybovycha -- on Java app not invoking `cl.exe`... are you *sure* you first ran `vcvarsall.bat` (Microsoft utility that sets up command environment for tools to work properly)? That is *important*. Otherwise, is this a "security" problem with the Java application invoking local system commands?  You can look to `scons` (Python-based build system) for running `vcvarsall.bat` to set things up, but `scons` is more "make-like", and not really suitable for Java builds either ...

Comment: @charley yeah, i am pretty sure =) manually ran it. or should i run it from within Java? because it seems that Java's PATH variable differs from the system one...

Comment: And you called the compiler in the same shell?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort well, i have a java code which runs the compiler with `ProcessBuilder` / `Runtime.exec()`... If you mean `cmd.exe` then yes, after running `envvars32.bat` from `cmd.exe` running `cl.exe` (from the `cmd.exe`) goes well

Comment: At last i solved it! The trick was to set environment for the process builder. Yeah, it is rather dummy but it just does the magick! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `*make` system is not usefull for Java project because `make` basically assumes one of "One file in, one file out" (e.g. `.c` to `.o`) or "N files in, one file out" (e.g. `*.o` to one of `.a`, `.dll`, `.exe`). With these "primitives" a build is performed.

But the Java compiler requires inherently "complete sourcetree in, comlete class-tree out".

Those two paradigmata don't match and trying to do will introduce more little nasty problems than its worth sooner or later. Been there, done that.

The best you can do is to call Ant or Maven (or whatever) from within a toplevel Makefile.

**Edit**: Not to forget two more things:

- Compiling Java stuff with `make` is a dark, arcane art. You will not find many people who know both Java and make and who can solve problems with that combination. Ant/Maven and Java is a standard combination. There is simply no problem finding help or advises with that combination.
- Many frameworks in Java require special compilation steps. In almost all cases there are plugins for Ant and Maven available. Using make you will have to reinvent the wheel every time again.

Comment: FreePascal/Delphi have the same problem. A compiler invocation can compile hundreds of files using the build-in dependency resolver or just one, depending on if you pass the name of a main program or a leaf module.

Comment: @AH Epic phrase for `dark, arcane art`! Still i need to run microsoft compiler from within the Java application. And it causes a trouble i can not fix for nearly 3 days. Do you have any ideas? (see my last comment on the question itself)

Comment: @shybovycha: using the MS compiler from within a Java app has nothing to do with this question. You should ask another, new question.

Answer (score 1):

Free Pascal provides its own build systems. See e.g.

http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq.pdf

the default makefiles (based on mostly generated gmake makefiles) are already cross- capable.

I don't know anybody who uses cmake with Free Pascal, and I've been on their maillists for over a decade.